# Problems booting into Windows 8 after installing Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I just attempted to set up my Lenovo Thinkpad Twist to dual boot. It had Windows 8.1 pre-installed.

I burned Ubuntu 13.04 to a USB and booted from that. I partitioned the drives allocating 50 GB for the Ubuntu partition. Ubuntu itself works fine, however when I try to boot back into windows I get an `error: can't find command 'drivemap'` and `error: invalid EFI file path`.

It looks like the problem is that the partition created 4 separate file systems:

- Lenovo_recovery
- 367MB Volume
- Windows8_OS
- WINRE_DRV.

There is a boot folder under the `Windows8_OS` file system, but I think that it is not being accessed by the boot menu.

Also, the boot menu only has an option for Windows 8 (loader) (on/dev/SDA4) and no Windows recovery environment. The parameters for this file are as follows:

```
setparams 'Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda4)'

insmod part_gpt
insmod ntfs
set root='hd0,gpt4'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hit-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4 FE3A79DE3A79947D
else
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=froot FE3A79DE3A79947D
fi
drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
chainloader +1
```

How do I fix this so that I can boot back into Windows 8?

Comment: Have you used "Boot-repair"?

Comment: As suggested Boot-Repair is the easiest way to fix this bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1024383